# pytesseract angle rotation and the impact on OCR quality

Tags: python, image, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

When my documents have an angle between 1 and 4°, there are line breaks in my OCR. Is it possible to straighten images between 1 and 4°?

In my main function I am first applying rotate_img and then deskew.

As for documents with a 180° or 90° rotation, I'd like my code to straighten images with a slight rotation cause I know for sure that it degrades the rendering of my OCR.

```
class ImageProcess:


    def rotate_img(self, image: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Fonction qui permet de redresser une image.

        Parameters
        ----------
        image: np.ndarray
            Image.

        Return
        ------
        np.array
            Image redressée.
        """
        
        if isinstance(image, bytes):
            # Convertir les bytes en tableau NumPy (image)
            im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))
        elif isinstance(image, np.ndarray):
            im = Image.fromarray(image)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Type d'entrée non pris en charge.")
        
        
        osd = pytesseract.image_to_osd(im, output_type='dict')
  

        rotate = osd['rotate']
        im_fixed = im.copy()
        
        if rotate == 90:
            im_fixed = im_fixed.transpose(Image.Transpose.ROTATE_270)
        else:
            im_fixed = im_fixed.rotate(rotate)
        
        return np.array(im_fixed)
 



    # Calculate skew angle of an image
    def getSkewAngle(self, cvImage) -> float:
        # Prep image, copy, convert to gray scale, blur, and threshold
        newImage = cvImage.copy()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(newImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9, 9), 0)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

        # Apply dilate to merge text into meaningful lines/paragraphs.
        # Use larger kernel on X axis to merge characters into single line, cancelling out any spaces.
        # But use smaller kernel on Y axis to separate between different blocks of text
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (30, 5))
        dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=5)

        # Find all contours
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)

        # Find largest contour and surround in min area box
        largestContour = contours[0]
        minAreaRect = cv2.minAreaRect(largestContour)

        # Determine the angle. Convert it to the value that was originally used to obtain skewed image
        angle = minAreaRect[-1]
        if angle < -45:
            angle += 90
        elif angle > 45:
            angle -= 90
        print("angle :", angle)
        return -1.0 * angle

    # Rotate the image around its center
    def rotateImage(self, cvImage, angle: float):
        newImage = cvImage.copy()
        (h, w) = newImage.shape[:2]
        center = (w // 2, h // 2)
        M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
        newImage = cv2.warpAffine(newImage, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
        return newImage

    # Deskew image
    def deskew(self, cvImage):
        
        angle = self.getSkewAngle(cvImage)
        return self.rotateImage(cvImage, -1.0 * angle)
```

do you have any ideas?